# Add an editable paragraph inside a Form in Kentico

Tags: kentico

I have a form, say A, inside this form I'd like to have an editable text field which can be maintained by a CMS content editor.

I was told that we cannot do it.

So I am wondering that can we make an editable text field some where else, e.g. the Webpart which contains the form, and display the text inside the form A?

Also, I do not want to save the text into the data table which maps to this form.

Here is the form
"Our staff will endeavour to respond to your message within 2 business days."
This is the text that I want to make an editable text field for.
[image]

Comment: why vote for "close"? I'm happy to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the editable text is NOT part of the form then there is no need to have it "inside" the form or as a form field.  You have a few options to add this editable text:

1. Inside any WYSIWYG editor, you can place a form or use the widget to add a form.  As long as your editable text is outside of the actual form, you can place this text before or after the form widget.

[image: WYSIWYG editor]

2. In the form itself, add a new Layout and place the form field labels and value macros as well as your custom text inside there.
3. You can create Categories which will group fields underneath that category together on the form.  See image below for an example.  This is a good way to store some "grouping" text for those similar fields.  This has to be edited within the form itself.
   [image: Form categories]

Comment: hi Brenden, thank you for the answer. I posted another question about Kentico, not sure whether you are interested in it or not, but here is the url:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203959/kentico-recaptcha-does-not-block-form-submission