# Kentico reCaptcha does not block form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, recaptcha, kentico

I have the reCaptcha FormControl in my WebPart

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
......

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Please type the word below. If required use the buttons to change or listen to the word.</label>
        <cms:RecaptchaControl ID="reCaptchaVld" runat="server" data-theme="clean" data-callback="cpCallBack();" PrivateKey="xxxxxxxxx" PublicKey="xxxxxxxxx" data-recaptcha="" CssClass="g-recaptcha" /> 
    </div>
```

I did a test that I filled all required field but leave the reCaptcha blank or unchecked,  clicked Submit button and the form was submitted successfully.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is your custom webpart, you need to call the `IsValid()` method to check whether the text was correctly entered.